# Reading a LPC2378 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, lpc, nxp

I can't get data off my ARM [LPC2378](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC2377_78.pdf) microcontroller - does it need UART or can any GPIO be used?

Comment: Could you provide some more info? Where do you want to get the info too? Those processes have lots of interfaces; Ethernet, CAN, UART, SPI, GPIO. JTAG could be used if it's only for development. You could use any of these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a level converter to actually use the UART (connecting to a PC, for example).

Check out this schematic [Keil eval board](http://www.keil.com/mcb2300/mcb2300-schematics.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about connecting the processor's UART to a PC's serial port, you can now get USB to RS232/TTL converters. One end goes into your PC's USB socket, and appears as a normal serial port; the other comes out to 5 V or 3.3 V signals that can be connected directly to your processor, with no level-shifting required.

We've used [TTL-232R-3V3](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/EvaluationKits/TTL-232R-3V3.htm) from FDTI Chip, which works perfectly for this kind of application.